# is it possible to log-in web page using telnet?

Tags: http, post, terminal, telnet

Below is what I tried to login webpage using telnet
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work!
What i get as a result in Terminal is the same source code in the right-bottom of picture. 
I want some advices, thanks.

Comment: It looks like that login form has a CAPTCHA, and you didn't include that in your telnet.

Comment: And the CAPTCHA probably uses a session variable, so you need to send the session ID cookie.